How do I set values in a pandas dataframe to the minimum of a group if a condition is met
This is some example data:
lst = [['PF2', 'E1', -500, -127, 199971, 200164, True, True], 
       ['PR2', 'E1', -500, -167, 199655, 200124, True, True],
       ['PF2', 'E1', -500, -167, 199645, 200124, False, True],
       ['PF2', 'E1', -400, -127, 199971, 200564, True, True], 
       ['PR2', 'E1', -400, -167, 199155, 200324, True, True]]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=["Name", "Part", "Rel_s", 
                                        "Rel_e", "Abs_s", "Abs_e",
                                        "Quality_Start", "Quality_End"])


I want to modify this dataframe to change the values of Abs_s to the smallest for each combination of Part and Rel_s (and the same thing for Abs_e with Part and Rel_e
with the largest value). This part works well with this code:
df['Abs_s'] = df.groupby(["Part", "Rel_s"])['Abs_s'].transform('min')

df['Abs_e'] = df.groupby(["Part", "Rel_e"])['Abs_e'].transform('max')


I like this solution because it seems simple and easily understandable; however, I also want to take into account the Quality values so that I take the minimum Abs_s value where Quality_Start is True and the maximum Abs_e where Quality_End is True. So in this case for E1, -500, the correct Abs_s value should be 199655 and not 199645. Bad Quality (False) values should be kept, if there are no good Quality (True) values to replace them with.
Can I add these conditions? How else could I do this transformation?

Quality_End is true when Abs_s is 199645 so why are you excluding that value?

Because Quality_End refers to the quality of the end position so is only relevant for Abs_e (e for end, s for start). I see how that was not phrased very clearly.

Gotcha. You should probably [edit] the question just to make that clear.

You can replace values with not Trues in Quality_Start and Quality_End to missing values first, here in Series.where:
g = (df.assign(Abs_s=df['Abs_s'].where(df['Quality_Start']),
               Abs_e=df['Abs_e'].where(df['Quality_End']))
       .groupby(["Part", "Rel_s"]))
    
df['Abs_s'] = g['Abs_s'].transform('min')
df['Abs_e'] = g['Abs_e'].transform('max')

print (df)    
  Name Part  Rel_s  Rel_e     Abs_s   Abs_e  Quality_Start  Quality_End
0  PF2   E1   -500   -127  199655.0  200564           True         True
1  PR2   E1   -500   -167  199655.0  200324           True         True
2  PF2   E1   -500   -167  199655.0  200324          False         True
3  PF2   E1   -400   -127  199155.0  200564           True         True
4  PR2   E1   -400   -167  199155.0  200324           True         True

How it working:
print (df.assign(Abs_s=df['Abs_s'].where(df['Quality_Start']),
                 Abs_e=df['Abs_e'].where(df['Quality_End'])))  

  Name Part  Rel_s  Rel_e     Abs_s   Abs_e  Quality_Start  Quality_End
0  PF2   E1   -500   -127  199971.0  200164           True         True
1  PR2   E1   -500   -167  199655.0  200124           True         True
2  PF2   E1   -500   -167       NaN  200124          False         True
3  PF2   E1   -400   -127  199971.0  200564           True         True
4  PR2   E1   -400   -167  199155.0  200324           True         True

If need integers in ouput is possible convert columns with missing values by Int64:
g = (df.assign(Abs_s=df['Abs_s'].where(df['Quality_Start']).astype('Int64'),
               Abs_e=df['Abs_e'].where(df['Quality_End']).astype('Int64'))
       .groupby(["Part", "Rel_s"]))

df['Abs_s'] = g['Abs_s'].transform('min')
df['Abs_e'] = g['Abs_e'].transform('max')

print (df)    
  Name Part  Rel_s  Rel_e   Abs_s   Abs_e  Quality_Start  Quality_End
0  PF2   E1   -500   -127  199655  200164           True         True
1  PR2   E1   -500   -167  199655  200164           True         True
2  PF2   E1   -500   -167  199655  200164          False         True
3  PF2   E1   -400   -127  199155  200564           True         True
4  PR2   E1   -400   -167  199155  200564           True         True

How it working:
print (df.assign(Abs_s=df['Abs_s'].where(df['Quality_Start']).astype('Int64'),
                 Abs_e=df['Abs_e'].where(df['Quality_End']).astype('Int64')))  

  Name Part  Rel_s  Rel_e   Abs_s   Abs_e  Quality_Start  Quality_End
0  PF2   E1   -500   -127  199655  200164           True         True
1  PR2   E1   -500   -167  199655  200164           True         True
2  PF2   E1   -500   -167    <NA>  200164          False         True
3  PF2   E1   -400   -127  199155  200564           True         True
4  PR2   E1   -400   -167  199155  200564           True         True

Testing with no match:
lst = [['PF2', 'E1', -500, -127, 199971, 200164, False, True], 
       ['PR2', 'E1', -500, -167, 199655, 200124, False, True],
       ['PF2', 'E1', -500, -167, 199645, 200124, False, True],
       ['PF2', 'E1', -400, -127, 199971, 200564, True, True], 
       ['PR2', 'E1', -400, -167, 199155, 200324, True, True]]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=["Name", "Part", "Rel_s", 
                                        "Rel_e", "Abs_s", "Abs_e",
                                        "Quality_Start", "Quality_End"])


g = (df.assign(Abs_s=df['Abs_s'].where(df['Quality_Start']).astype('Int64'),
               Abs_e=df['Abs_e'].where(df['Quality_End']).astype('Int64'))
       .groupby(["Part", "Rel_s"]))

df['Abs_s'] = g['Abs_s'].transform('min')
df['Abs_e'] = g['Abs_e'].transform('max')

print (df)    
  Name Part  Rel_s  Rel_e   Abs_s   Abs_e  Quality_Start  Quality_End
0  PF2   E1   -500   -127    <NA>  200164          False         True
1  PR2   E1   -500   -167    <NA>  200164          False         True
2  PF2   E1   -500   -167    <NA>  200164          False         True
3  PF2   E1   -400   -127  199155  200564           True         True
4  PR2   E1   -400   -167  199155  200564           True         True


print (df.assign(Abs_s=df['Abs_s'].where(df['Quality_Start']).astype('Int64'),
                 Abs_e=df['Abs_e'].where(df['Quality_End']).astype('Int64')))  
  Name Part  Rel_s  Rel_e   Abs_s   Abs_e  Quality_Start  Quality_End
0  PF2   E1   -500   -127    <NA>  200164          False         True
1  PR2   E1   -500   -167    <NA>  200164          False         True
2  PF2   E1   -500   -167    <NA>  200164          False         True
3  PF2   E1   -400   -127  199155  200564           True         True
4  PR2   E1   -400   -167  199155  200564           True         True

EDIT:
#one groupby with created 2 temporary columns
g = (df.assign(Abs_s_t=df['Abs_s'].where(df['Quality_Start']).astype('Int64'),
               Abs_e_t=df['Abs_e'].where(df['Quality_End']).astype('Int64'))
       .groupby(["Part", "Rel_s"])) 
 
#if need replace by original values
df['Abs_s'] = g['Abs_s_t'].transform('min').fillna(df['Abs_s']) 
df['Abs_e'] = g['Abs_e_t'].transform('max').fillna(df['Abs_e'])

#if need replace by min/max values per groups
df['Abs_s1'] = g['Abs_s_t'].transform('min').fillna(g['Abs_s'].transform('min')) 
df['Abs_e1'] = g['Abs_e_t'].transform('max').fillna(g['Abs_e'].transform('max')) 

print (df)    
  Name Part  Rel_s  Rel_e   Abs_s   Abs_e  Quality_Start  Quality_End  Abs_s1  Abs_e1
0  PF2   E1   -500   -127  199971  200164          False         True  199645  200164
1  PR2   E1   -500   -167  199655  200164          False         True  199645  200164
2  PF2   E1   -500   -167  199645  200164          False         True  199645  200164
3  PF2   E1   -400   -127  199155  200564           True         True  199155  200564
4  PR2   E1   -400   -167  199155  200564           True         True  199155  200564


Would this solution result in NA/NaN in the output, if there was no good quality value to replace it with?

@Mz_Chen - Exactly, if no match get NaNs

Ah, thank you. But I do need to retain the low quality value if there is no high quality value to replace it with. I suppose if I made a copy of the orignal data, then I could afterwards look for NaNs and replace them with their values from the original dataframe. Or is there a simpler way?

@Mz_Chen - So it means in last paragraph instead <NA> should be 200164 from column Abs_e?

Yes. I think this modification works:
`
g = (df.assign(Abs_s_t=df['Abs_s'].where(df['Quality_Start']).astype('Int64'))
.groupby(["Part", "Rel_s"]))
df['Abs_s'] = g['Abs_s_t'].transform('min').fillna(df['Abs_s'])
g = (df.assign(Abs_e_t=df['Abs_e'].where(df['Quality_End']).astype('Int64'))
.groupby(["Part", "Rel_e"]))
df['Abs_e'] = g['Abs_e_t'].transform('max').fillna(df['Abs_e'])
`

@Mz_Chen - Is correct .fillna(df['Abs_s']) ? Not per groups like .fillna(g['Abs_s'].transform('min')) ?

@Mz_Chen - Added EDIT part to my solution - repalce by original values or by min per groups.

Some filtering with groupby will do the trick and only the values where the condition is True will change. All the other values where Quality is False in will stay the same.
start = df['Quality_Start']
end = df['Quality_End']
df.loc[start, 'Abs_s'] = df[start].groupby(["Part", "Rel_s"])['Abs_s'].transform('min')
df.loc[end, 'Abs_e'] = df[end].groupby(["Part", "Rel_s"])['Abs_e'].transform('max')

End result:




Name
Part
Rel_s
Rel_e
Abs_s
Abs_e
Quality_Start
Quality_End




0
PF2
E1
-500
-127
199655
200164
True
True


1
PR2
E1
-500
-167
199655
200164
True
True


2
PF2
E1
-500
-167
199645
200164
False
True


3
PF2
E1
-400
-127
199155
200564
True
True


4
PR2
E1
-400
-167
199155
200564
True
True



